# How can Thor be worthy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-endgame, mjolnir

When I read [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212208/why-was-thor-doubtful-about-his-worthiness-to-mjolnir/212223#212223) the answer seemed to be simple to me. Thor's life in the past years was definitely not acting exemplary or worthy of a king. Not only does he throw away his life, but he also doesn't care about his people or the universe.

So my question is the opposite in a way.

**How can Thor still be worthy after his behavior in *Avengers: Endgame*?**

Comment: Because despite the survivor guilt, the PTSD and the slight paunchiness, he still stepped up and went through the gate into the past.

Comment: @Valorum so did Tony Stark?

Comment: @tox123 - Sure, but it's not really clear if Tony ever dealt with his demons. In fact all the evidence suggests that he didn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First off a minor correction, Thor *does* care about the universe and its people. That is why he was acting the way he was, if he didn’t care it wouldn’t have hit him as hard.

The reason he is worthy is because despite everything he does eventually step up to take the fight back again. However, unlike Valorum’s comment I would argue that he wasn’t worthy when he went into the past. Whilst it took guts to go back and was a step to becoming worthy again he was still running away, literally at times.

The turning point is actually just before he summons Mjolnir. Frigga talks sense into him and he realises he needs to step up and the culmination of that is trying to summon Mjolnir which puts him back into the fight. He has made himself worthy because despite everything he now wants to continue again. I.e, his actions in the moment were worthy and from then on he carried on being worthy again.

Answer (score 2):

Truth is, beneath all that drunkenness and denial, Thor does still care about the universe, and his people.

Thor could have simply left New Asgard after helping his people settle in. He didn't.

He could've denied being a part of the Avenger's mission. He didn't.

At heart, he is still the same Thor, who does care about everything. The whole reason he is depressed in the movie, is because he cared so much, and couldn't deal with being absolutely ineffective.

That is why he is still worthy. That despite having lost so much, despite having lost all hope, he still leapt at the chance of making things right.